# tomcat unble to sart with clipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, port, tomcat8, log-files

Tomcat showing unable to start using eclipse marce or luna but tomcat 7 or 8  running fine under windows 8.1 through cmd by the startup.bat but problem start with when ever try to work with eclipse, I have clear the log and change the directory of tomcat also and change the eclipse workspace but same result.
thanks

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting in eclipse.

Comment: unable to start localhost

Comment: Nobody could help you if you don't provide enough information. Please attach screenshot or error log.

Comment: org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:scwcd2' did not find a matching property.

Comment: org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:scwcd2' did not find a matching property